# Applying the derivative in the scope of Leibnitz test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let,
$$\sum_{n=1}a_{n}=\sum_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(2n)}$$

By studing $\sum |a_{n}|$ I got divergence, so I couldt'n conclued anything about $\sum a_{n}$. Then I considered $b_{n}= \frac{1}{\ln(2n)}$ and applied the Leinbnitz test.

One got,

$\lim b_{n}=0$

Then I found the derivative of $b_{n}$. I got $-\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$, that is negative for all $n \geq 1$. So $b_{n}$ is decreasing.

By the Leibnitz test $\sum b_{n}$ converges and so $\sum (-1)^nb_{n}$ converges to.

My doubt is, if I can use the derivative to know if $b_{n}$ is decreasing in order to apply the Leibnitz test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method that you mentioned is almost correct. Notice that derivative of $b_n$ doesn't make sense. Instead just define $f(x)=1/(ln(2x))$. Then $b_n=f(n)$ and derivative of $f$ shows that $f$ is decreasing, and hence so is $b_n$